# How to calculate the height of conical?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I need to calculate the value of "$f$" ,where is demonstrated at shape, "$f$" must be function of "$R$". How this calculation is possible?

[image]

Comment: Which variables are assumed to be given? I think $R$ is given - maybe also $\alpha$? or $a$?

Comment: It's fairly easy to see that $\cos{\alpha} = \frac{R}{R+f}$ and from this you can solve $f$.

Comment: Dear Matti P, thanks.

Comment: But I couldn't understand how you find "cos α" is equal to "R /R + f"? maybe you want to say cot α=R /(R + f)?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Conical]

Let's take the point where the line touches the circle, and call it $A$. The centre of the circle is $C$ and the point where the lines cross each other is $F$. We are interested in the angle $ACF$. If we draw the line $AC$, we see that it forms a triangle with the other lines drawn in the picture. We then see that $ACF = \alpha$.

Now, the cosine of $\alpha$ is
$$
\cos{\alpha} = \frac{R}{R +  f} \Rightarrow R = R\cos{\alpha } + f \cos{\alpha}
\Rightarrow f = (1-\cos{\alpha})R
$$

Comment: because my English is not strong so I couldn't imagine what is your mean. I am sorry. if it is possible, can you draw figure of your explanation?

Comment: what is the "line AR"?

Comment: Dear Matti P, I need your help? please help me.